# array_search() not finding 0th element

Tags: php, arrays

I have a large `array` of stock ticker symbols, as I am for a project writing a stock market simulation webapp. One of my helper functions is one to determine whether the entered stock is valid by checking the array for the symbol. To do this, I am using `array_search()`.
The problem I have is one by checking edge cases. It seems that the search isn't picking up the 0th element, even though it picks up other elements completely fine.
Here is part of the array:

```
[0] => AAC
[1] => AACC
[2] => AACOU
[3] => AACOW
[4] => AAIT
[5] => AAME
[6] => AAON
[7] => AAPL
[8] => AAWW
[9] => AAXJ
[10] => ABAX
[11] => ABCB
[12] => ABCD
[13] => ABCO
[14] => ABFS
[15] => ABIO
[16] => ABMD
[17] => ABTL
[18] => ABVA
[19] => ACAD
[20] => ACAS
[21] => ACAT
[22] => ACCL
```

Etc, etc.
As said before, it works fine for other elements, just not the 0th one. It returns `FALSE` when searching for AAC.

Here is the PHP code I am using.

```
<?php   
                if(isset($_GET[stock])) {
                    $ticker = $_GET[stock];
                    $ticker = trim($ticker);
                    print("<pre>Ticker is $ticker</pre>");

                    print("Validity: " .        Stock::isValidStock($ticker));

                    print('<pre>');
                    $stock = Stock::getStockList();
                    print_r($stock);
                    print((bool)array_search('AAC', $stock));
                    print('</pre></br>');
                }
            ?>
```

[Here is the test web page I'm using.](http://alexandstein.com/Testing/?stock=AAC)
You can change the stock by editing the query string in the url. 
As I said, `?stock=AAC` returns false, while something like `?stock=GOOG` is true.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) returns the key of the first match if one is found. When said key is 0 and you cast it into a bool, it will become false.

What you want to do is compare it to `false` using the [not identical operator `===`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) :

```
//if you don't need the index you can skip assigning it to a variable
$index = array_search('AAC', $stock); 

if ($index !== false) 
{
    // found!
}
```

Comment: Ahhh! I see what I did. I completely forgot that it returns the index, as opposed to an isFound() sort of function. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and i found one problem is in this line

```
 print((bool)array_search('AAC', $stock));
```

you are casting  it to bool and because of this it returns nothing for 0th element.

its working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/VPveZH